# How to enable media sharing in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-player

I'm trying to configure media sharing under Windows 8 (pro). I found an option in **PC settings->HomeGroup** *Allow all devices on the network such as TVs and game console to play my shared content* but it's disabled (I've attached a screenshot).

I saw that the Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service is disabled, but when I'm trying to run it I get an error **Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start**

[image: Windows 8 HomeGroup Settings]

Comment: In Windows Services, OPEN THE "Media Player Network Sharing Service" and check the dependencies tab, see if those services listed are started also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Services, OPEN THE "Media Player Network Sharing Service" and check the dependencies tab, see if those services listed are started also.